# Hide white border in image downloaded from web browser after using plt.imshow

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I am doing a secret sharing implementation on images. This is part of the code for displaying the original image:

```
image_path = "lena.jpg"
image_array = load_grayscale_image(image_path)

plt.imshow(image_array, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

The image being printed here is having a white border when I try to download and save it by right-clicking and save image as...

I need the border removed as it is interfering with my accuracy values.

The editor I'm using is Google Colab. I tried the following:

- `plt.savefig('image.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)`
- `plt.figure(figsize=(256 / 100.0, 256 / 100.0), dpi=100.0)`
- `plt.tight_layout()`

None of these are working. I'm not sure if this is editor-specific or I'm doing something wrong.

This is the image I'm getting after saving, it still has whitespace - https://i.stack.imgur.com/86vFs.png

Comment: What do you mean by whitespace? White background?

Comment: White border
Will edit the question accordingly

Comment: You marked the answer as accepted yesterday and today you retracted that without any comment. Maybe you could provide feedback - it is nice to know what's working and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to trim off the white borders, if so you need to use an image processing package like PIL/Pillow rather than a plotting package like matplotlib.

Here's a way:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

# Load image
im = Image.ooen('IMAGE.PNG')

# Drop alpha channel, and invert because trimming functions remove black, not white 
bbox = ImageOps.invert(im.convert('RGB')).getbbox()
```

**Output**

```
(10, 10, 460, 460)
```

Now crop to bounding box:

```
cropped = im.crop(bbox)
cropped.save('result.png
```